# If the number is divisible by 10 then print Yes Otherwise, print No

Tags: java

You are provided an array A of size N that contains non-negative integers. Your task is to determine whether the number that is formed by selecting the last digit of all the N numbers is divisible by 10.

code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.Math;

import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = 0;
        N = s.nextInt();
        double ans = 0;
        
        int[] data = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            data[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr[i] = data[i] % 10;
        }

        for (int i = 0, j = N - 1; i < N; i++, j--) {
            double res = arr[i] * Math.pow(10,j);
            ans = res + ans;
        }

        int ans1 = (int) ans;
        if (ans % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

not able to get all the test cases right, what is the issue?

Comment: How many numbers do you input? Perhaps your cast to `int` is causing an integer overflow? Also in your last `if` statement, you are using `ans` instead of `ans1`.

Comment: What is the test case you're having an issue with?

Comment: what is meant by "selecting the last digit of all the N numbers"? Joining?

Comment: eg: Last digit of 85
 is 5
.
Last digit of 25
 is 5
.
Last digit of 65
 is 5
.
Last digit of 21
 is 1
.
last digit of14 is 4
Therefore the number formed is 55514
 which is not divisible by 10
.


Value of N in the above case is 5

Comment: last comment, assuming it is the correct one now, should be added to the question... anyways see my previous comment about `double`  For example `10000000000000001.0 % 10` is `0` and not `1`

Comment: It would be useful (and interesting) for us to know what test case(s) failed.

Comment: @WJS Online judges for these sorts of questions will not usually show the input for the failed tests.

Comment: @Unmitigated Didn't realize that.  Some places show something like "Failed for ..."

Comment: @WJS example: `17 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` (based on my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76547425/if-the-number-is-divisible-by-10-then-print-yes-otherwise-print-no#comment134965363_76547425)) is resulting in `Yes` (but ending in `1` - not divisible by 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number formed by the last digit of each number in the array is only divisible by 10 if the last digit is 0. You will therefore only need to check if the last number in the array is divisible by 10. There is no need to construct the complete number.

So this could be the complete solution:

```java
if (arr[N - 1] % 10 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The number formed by all last digits is divisible by 10 iff the last digit of the last number is 0

Comment: They clearly already have the divisible by 10 part solved because their code includes `if(ans%10==0){`

Comment: @Ian it means that only (the last digit of) the last number must be tested; all other numbers are irrelevant

Comment: @user16320675 that's not true: "Your task is to determine whether the number that is formed by selecting the last digit of all the N numbers is divisible by 10."

Comment: @user16320675 If the input is "2 17 317 5 80" the Nth numbers would be 317 and 80, the last digits would be 7 and 0, 7+0 = 7,  7 isn't divisible by 10 so the output it false. That's my understanding of the question at least.

Comment: @user16320675 There are details missing in the question and ambiguities, but I think the asker meant every Nth number based on this line of their code: `N = s.nextInt();`, and I've made the assumption that asker meant sum. However it's clear the question isn't clear.

Comment: My interpretation is given "2 17 317 5 80"  The number under test would be 27750.  And would be true.  This agrees with both @user16320675's interpretation and what the OP has implemented.  So all one needs to do is check if the last digit of the last number is 0.

Comment: @IanNewson The question seems to be the same as here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-the-number-formed-by-the-last-digits-of-n-numbers-is-divisible-by-10-or-not/

Comment: @WJS Indeed, it should be the same question as here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-the-number-formed-by-the-last-digits-of-n-numbers-is-divisible-by-10-or-not/

Comment: @user16320675 I'm not sure what's happening here, you initially said "only (the last digit of) the last number must be tested" which is what I questioned, but now you're claiming it is actually a list of numbers. Anyway, I don't come to SO for arguments, so have a good day!

Comment: @IanNewson  Keep in mind that the OP may not fully understand the "shortcut."  The OP is storing the numbers in an array., then iterating on that array, storing the last digits of the numbers in a new array, then creating a new number by multiplying those digits by powers of 10, all in the same order as the numbers were entered.  If the new number ends in 0 then it is divisible by 10.  A more important question, imho, is what is not working.